# Lowest score that two students could have received

Tags: algebra-precalculus, average

In a class of 20 students, a test was administered, scored only in whole numbers from 0 to 10. At least one student got every possible score, and the average was 7. Compare quantity A with quantity B (i.e. Quantity A is greater, less or equal to quantity B) given below:

- Quantity A: $4$
- Quantity B: The lowest score that two students could have received

### Question: What does the wording "The lowest score that two students could have received" mean?

I solved this one as follows:

Total score of $20$ students $= 20*7= 140$

As at least one student got every possible score, so $11$ students get 55 in total. And rest of the students can get $140-55= 85$ in total.

Now, to minimize the score of $9th$ student, I have to maximize $8$ students score, which is $10$. so, their total = $8*10=80$, and the $9th$ student can get $5$.

So, I get lowest 2 scores of $2$ students are $0$ and $1$. In total $2$.

But, right answer I find in book is $5$. What am I missing?

Comment: It means, choose any $2$ out of $20$ students (you have $\binom{20}{2}=190$ ways to do it), sum up their scores, and tell us what is the lowest value that you got.

Comment: BTW, if anything, I'd ask **what does the wording "At least one student got every possible score" mean**. How can a student take a single test, and get more than one score for that test???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can have a lot of fun with the ambiguity of the English language, but when this ambiguity crops up in a math problem it is not so much fun.

I would interpret a "score that two students could have received" as an integer $n$ such that there exists a list of $20$ scores satisfying all the requirements of the problem, and in that list of scores the integer $n$ appears at least twice.

I would interpret "the lowest score that two students could have received" to mean the minimum value of $n$ over all values $n$ could take in the previous paragraph over all lists of scores that satisfy the requirements of the problem. This value is $5$.

One of the ambiguities in the problem statement is that a score received by two students *could* (in some circumstances) mean the sum of the two students' scores. In that case the lowest score received by two students is $0+1=1$. (It not only "could be" $1$, it *must* be $1$.)

The reason to choose the interpretation leading to the answer $5$ is that this is the more usual interpretation in problems like this. If the sum of scores were intended, I would expect some indication such as "combined score".

Answer (score 0):

I think that "the lowest score that two students could have received"  is $m$ means that there are at least TWO students with vote $m$, and if two students get the same vote than it is $\geq m$.

In your case there are $11$ students with votes $0,1,2,\dots,10$ and the remaining ones get votes $x_{12},\dots,x_{20}$ with $x_i\in \{0,1,\dots,10\}$.

Since the average is $7$ then
$$140=7\cdot 20=\sum_{k=1}^{11}k+ \sum_{k=12}^{20}x_k$$
which implies that
$$\sum_{k=12}^{20}x_k=140-55=85.$$
Let $m$ be minimum value of $x_{12},\dots,x_{20}$ then
$$85=\sum_{k=12}^{20}x_k\leq 10\cdot 8+m= 80+m\quad\Rightarrow \quad m\geq 5.$$
$m=5$ can be obtained when $x_{12}=\cdots=x_{19}=10$ and $x_{20}=5$.

Answer (score 0):

I think here is some misleading interpretation:

First of all, "***The lowest score that two students could have received***" this means **Two among all the 20 score which is equal and two distinct students got that score.**

The scores we can get are like this:

0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 (11 distinct score),

10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10(8 of the remaining 9 student may got this to score 80 of 85 remaining point)

and 5 (the last student have got to make 85 points).

Now, look into the above list of scores. We see 2 students have got 5 among the lowest scores. Here is our answer.

Secondly, "***At least one student got every possible score***" this statement still seams misleading to me.